# Jquery communication with local server

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

So I am trying to communicate with a local java server via a jquery post method but am I am not having much luck. The post code I am using is:

```
    $.post('localhost:5051/receive', {'plugs':client['plugins']});
```

where client['plugins'] is a string that has a confirmed value.

The servlet I am attempting to receive this with is (all necessary imports):

```
public class BaseServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public BaseServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String plugins = request.getParameter("plugs");
        System.out.println("HERE");
        System.out.println(plugins);
    }
}
```

It seems as if this servlet isn't receiving any communication from the post method.

Note the javascript is running on a local html file I am just opening in my browser.

The following is the base server code with all the necessary imports:

```
public class MyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         Server server = new Server();
        Connector connector = new SocketConnector();
    connector.setPort(5051);
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});

    ServletHandler handler=new ServletHandler();
    server.setHandler(handler);

    handler.addServletWithMapping("BaseServlet", "/receive");

    server.start();
    server.join();
    }
}
```

Thanks and advance I apologize if this is rather intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

When you say `$.post('localhost:5051/receive'` you probably mean `$.post('http://localhost:5051/receive'` but that will only work if you are already using that host and port (the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) restricts this for security reasons) so you might as well use a relative URI and say `$.post('/receive'`

Edit. I've just spotted:

> Note the javascript is running on a local html file I am just opening in my browser.

As I said previously, the page the JS runs in **must** be on [the same host and port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) as the URI you are requested data from.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately this did not resolve it.